# React useCallback with Parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, callback

Using React's `useCallback` hook is essentially just a wrapper around `useMemo` specialized for functions to avoid constantly creating new function instances within components' props. My question comes from when you need to pass an argued to the callback created from the memoization.

For instance, a callback created like so...

```
const Button: React.FunctionComponent = props => {
    const onClick = React.useCallback(() => alert('Clicked!'), [])
    return <button onClick={onClick}>{props.children}</button>
}
```

is a simple example of a memoized callback and required no external values passed into it in order to accomplish its job. However, if I want to create a generic memoized callback for a `React.Dipatch<React.SetStateAction>` function type, then it would require arguments...for example:

```
const Button: React.FunctionComponent = props => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false)
    const genericSetLoadingCb = React.useCallback((x: boolean) => () => setLoading(x), [])

    return <button onClick={genericSetLoadingCb(!loading)}>{props.children}</button>
}
```

In my head, this seems like its the exact same as doing the following...

```
const Button: React.FunctionComponent = props => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false)
    return <button onClick={() => setLoading(!loading)}>{props.children}</button>
}
```

which would let defeat the purpose of memoizing the function because it would still be creating a new function on every render since `genericSetLoadingCb(false)` would just be returning a new function on each render as well.

Is this understanding correct, or does the pattern described with arguments still maintain the benefits of memoization?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I will provide an answer with a slightly different use case, but it will still answer your question.

#### Motivation and Problem Statement

Let's consider following (similar to your `genericSetLoadingCb`) higher order function `genericCb`:

```
  const genericCb = React.useCallback(
    (param) => (e) => setState({ ...state, [param]: e.target.value }),
    []
  );
```

Say we use it in the following situation where `Input` is a *memoized component* created using [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo):

```
  <Input value={state.firstName} onChange={genericCb('firstName')} />
```

Since `Input` is memoized component, we would like the *function generated by* `genericCb('firstName')` to remain the same across re-renders, so that the memoized component doesn't re-render needlessly.

Below we will see how to achieve this.

#### Solution

Now, the way  we constructed `genericCb` above is we ensured that it remains the same across renders (due to usage of `useCallback`).

However, each time you call `genericCb` to create a new  function out of it like this:

```
genericCb("firstName")
```

The *returned function will still be different on each render*.
To also ensure the returned function is memoized for some input, you should additionally use some memoizing approach:

```
  import memoize from "fast-memoize";
  ....

  const genericCb = React.useCallback(
    memoize((param) => (e) => setState({ ...state, [param]: e.target.value })),
    []
  );
```

Now if you call   `genericCb("firstName")` to generate a function, *it will return same function on each render, provided `"firstName"` also remains the same*.

#### Remarks

As pointed out in the comments above solution using `useCallback` seems to produce warning (it didn't in my project though):

> React Hook useCallback received a function whose dependencies are
> unknown. Pass an inline function instead

It seems the warning is there because we didn't pass inline function to `useCallback`. The solution I found to get rid of this warning based on [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/19240) github thread is to use `useMemo` to imitate `useCallback` like this:

```
// Use this; this doesn't produce the warning anymore  
const genericCb = React.useMemo(
    () =>
      memoize(
        (param) => (e) => setState({ ...state, [param]: e.target.value })
      ),
    []
  );
```

Also I would like to note that simply using memoize without `useCallback` (or `useMemo` as in the update) wouldn't work, as on next render it would invoke memoize from fresh like this:

```
let memoized = memoize(fn)
 
memoized('foo', 3, 'bar')
memoized('foo', 3, 'bar') // cache hit

memoized = memoize(fn); // without useCallback (or useMemo) this would happen on next render 

// Now the previous cache is lost
```

Comment: ok, so my assumption that using just `React.useCallback` on a argument receiving HOF provides no value unless you _also_ memoize the internal function within the `useCallback` usage.

Comment: @m_callens I believe so as useCallback would memoize the function you passed to it, not the function which is created when you invoke `genericSetLoadingCb`

Comment: would it be better the use `React.useMemo` or an inner `React.useCallback` instead of `fast-memoize` to reduce dependencies?

Comment: @m_callens memoize will create different function for memoizedcb(true) and for memoizedcb(false). Can you make useCallback dependant on argument like that?

Comment: In TypeScript, it gives us this eslint warning: "React Hook useCallback received a function whose dependencies are unknown. Pass an inline function instead.". What to put in dependency array instead of disabling the eslint warning?

Comment: @JeafGilbert I am afraid I don't know what is best way to go in that case, I didn't get that warning, I don't use Typescript. Maybe you can ignore it, if you make sure you don't have stale closures.

Comment: the eslint warning shows up on js project, too

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava thanks so much, that was very genius solution, with `useMemo` and `momize`, that worked for me, but  fast-memoize package did not work for me. I used Lodash momoize

Comment: @shadi I don't  know why `fast-memoize` didn't work for you, for me it did.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava, the only thing that is different from your example is that my first parameter is not a string type, but a function type.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest creating a map of memoized callbacks for each possible argument value:

```
const genericSetLoadingCb = React.useMemo(() =>
  {
    [true]: () => setLoading(true),
    [false]: () => setLoading(false),
  },
  []
);
```

Thus a memoized version will be the same for each value:

```
return <button onClick={genericSetLoadingCb[!loading]}>{props.children}</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use callback for inner function:

```
const Button: React.FunctionComponent = props => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false)
    const genericSetLoadingCb = (x: boolean) => React.useCallback(() => setLoading(x), [])

    return <button onClick={genericSetLoadingCb(!loading)}>{props.children}</button>
}
```

So every time you call genericSetLoadingCb it would return memoized function. It works but react recommends to place useCallback inside component directly or inside another hook.