# Prevent Child Rerendering if Parent is Rerendered Using Hooks

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, memoization, use-reducer, react-memo

My bestSellerDummy data doesn't change, so I'd like to prevent the same Product child to be rerendered if parent rerenders. I have tried using useMemo in parent and React.memo in child but no luck, it's still showing log 'Rendering Product component..' every time parent rerenders. What am I missing here? Please advice.

Note: Parent is expected to be rerendered every time I call addToCart function (of CartContext) in a Product component.

I'm using CartContext, maybe related to this, I'm not sure. Here is the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-moore-po1c6?file=/src/App.js

**Home.tsx**

```
const [bestSellerDummy] = useState(
  [...new Array(5)].map((item, key) => ({
    id: key,
    imageUri:'https://1.jpg',
    name: 'My Dummy 1',
    price: 25,
  })),
);

const bestSellers = useMemo(() => {
  return bestSellerDummy.map((productDummy, key) => {
    return (
      <Product key={key} product={productDummy} />
    );
  });
}, [bestSellerDummy]);

return (
  ...
  {bestSellers}
  ...
)
```

**Product.tsx**

```
const Product: FunctionComponent<IProductProps> = (
  productProps,
) => {
  ...
  console.log('Rendering Product component..');
  ...
}

export default React.memo(Product);
```

**=== EDIT: MY VERSION OF ANSWER ===**

Finally! After playing around with `useCallback`, `useMemo`, `fast-memoize` plugin.. What suits the best for me is using `useReducer` in Context combine with wrapping the expensive component with `React.memo`. I think this is the most clean and elegant way to optimize child components. Working sandbox is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-albattani-8x7h9?file=/src/App.js

Comment: What causes the parent element re-render? Could you provide a minimal reproducible example via Codesandbox?

Comment: @dongnhan Parent is expected to be rerendered every time I call addToCart function (of CartContext) in a Product component.

Comment: You can also pass second callback to compare when to `render` in [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo). It would be great if you add sandbox. Otherwise its hard to tell from this

Comment: Here we go: https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-moore-po1c6?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `useContext`, your component will always re-renders.

> When the nearest <MyContext.Provider> above the component updates, this Hook will trigger a rerender with the latest context value passed to that MyContext provider. Even if an ancestor uses React.memo or shouldComponentUpdate, a rerender will still happen starting at the component itself using useContext.

Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

I was trying to refactor your code using the 2nd strategy pointed from the docs: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15156#issuecomment-474590693.

However, I soon realized that the `addToCart` function has `cartItems` as its dependency, so whenever `cartItems` changes, `addToCart` changes and it's kind of impossible to avoid re-renders since every `Product` component use `addToCart` function.

That leads me to the use of `useReducer` because [React guarantees that its `dispatch` is stable and won't change during re-renders.](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)

So here's the working Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/red-feather-dc7x6?file=/src/App.js:786-797

Comment: Ahh, okay. Thank you, dongnhan! It is so neat and works like a charm ✨

Comment: Btw, when we need dynamic qty as onPress param, it breaks the memoization and the issue comes back: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-albattani-8x7h9?file=/src/App.js. Any idea to solve this without 'fast-memoize' plugin? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61255053/react-usecallback-with-parameter)

Comment: @JeafGilbert, change this line into this `onAddToCart={handleAddToCart}`. By using `onAddToCart={(addQty)=>{handleAddToCart(addQty)}`, you are creating new a handler everytime which causes the re-renders.

Comment: Solved! https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-albattani-8x7h9?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2):

Wrap `BestSellers` component with `React.memo` too. Don't use `useMemo` to avoid unnecessary component updating because it may cause bugs. It is used for computing expensive values.

Source: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo

Comment: I think this is also correct! I combined with dongnhan answer as my version of answer (provided in edited question). I really appreciate it, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is the best way to clear your concepts about useCallback, useMemo and useEffect.

**App.js**

```js
import Child1 from "./Child1";
import Child2 from "./Child2";
import { useState, useEffect, useMemo, useCallback } from "react";
function App() {
  const [x, setX] = useState(0);
  const [y, setY] = useState(0);
  console.log("Parent");
  const printx = useCallback(() => {
    console.log("x:" + x);
  }, [x]);
  useEffect(() => {
    printx();
    console.log("-------");
  }, [printx]);
  const child1 = useMemo(() => {
    return <Child1 x={x} />;
  }, [x]);
  const child2 = useMemo(() => {
    return <Child2 y={y} />;
  }, [y]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Parent</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setX(x + 1)}>X+</button>
      <button onClick={() => setY(y + 1)}>Y+</button>
      {child1}
      {child2}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Child1.js**

```js
const Child1 = ({ x }) => {
  console.log("Child1");
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Child 1:{x}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Child1;
```

**Child2.js**

```js
const Child2 = ({ y }) => {
  console.log("Child2");
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Child 2:{y}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Child2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```js
const [bestSellerDummy, setBestSellerDummy] = useState([]); // default empty

// get data from `useCallback`
const sellerData = React.useCallback(
  () => {
    return [...new Array(5)].map((item, key) => ({
     id: key,
     imageUri:'https://1.jpg',
     name: 'My Dummy 1',
     price: 25,
  }))

  }, []
);

useEffect( () => {
  setBestSellerDummy( sellerData() ); // set data when screen rendered from `useCallback`
}, [])

const bestSellers = useMemo(() => {
// ....
}, [bestSellerDummy]);
 return (
//  ...
{bestSellers}
//  ...
)
```

Comment: @Jeaf try removing `...` from `[...new Array(5)]`

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you are using dynamic index for key . when you used dynamic key always react re render this .So use product id or some unique key for this then  problem will be solved . I also have same problem and i resolved it