# How to pass arguments to useCallback

Tags: reactjs

How in this example from the Shopify Polaris library (ReactJS)

```
function TextFieldExample() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('Jaded Pixel');

  const handleChange = useCallback((newValue) => setValue(newValue), []);

  return <TextField label="Store name" value={value} onChange={handleChange} />;
}
```

is the argument `newValue` being passed to the `useCallback`?

I tried to lookup the source of the Polaris library but I couldn't come to a practical conclusion.

Edit: Maybe it would help to understand why this is necessary in React:

```
const useForceUpdate = ()
=> {
[value, setValue] = useState(0);

return () => setValue(value => value + 1);
}
```

To call this inside a component, I have to

```
const forceUpdate = useForceUpdate();
forceUpdate();
```

instead of just

```
useForceUpdate();
```

Comment: does this answer help you `https://stackoverflow.com/a/61256814/11043676`

Comment: I wonder at which position is the argument passed to the function of props.onChange. The argument is obviously the new value of the textfield, but where does it get passed? Does this happen by the ReactJS library?

Answer (score 1):

`useCallback` returns a function that will be used in `onChange` prop. Inside TextField component props.onChange will be called when value will be changed. Somehing like this (just an example):

```
//TextField
function TextFiled(props) {
   const handleChange = (event) => {
      props.onChange(event.target.value); // here you function that was returned by useCallback
   }

   return <input onChange={handleChange}/>
}
```